# Is this sql request correct?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having some problems with Ajax+php registration lately.
I ultimately came to the conclusion that the root of all problems would be somewhere in the sql request. Can anyone please take a look at it?

```
$insert_new_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,email,password,age,sex,city,timereg,frcode) VALUES('$fname_received','$lname_received','$email_received','$password_received','$dob_received','$sex_received','$city_received,'$timepassreg','$frcode')");
```

Comment: no. it relies on deprecated methods

Comment: Do you escape the user input before adding into the query?

Comment: yeah I escaped the inputs, of course.. what about the sql request itself? does it appear to be wrong technically?

Comment: Also look at city_received

Comment: got it, it's all because of that one symbol...

Comment: isn't it essential to escape mysql_query inputs?

Comment: also could you please clarify what you meant by relying on deprecated methods?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Does any newcomer on SO know about prepared statements?! Please read about prepared statements :)

Comment: Oleg, Why? Has google broken? ;-)

Comment: so you recommend using those prepared statements instead of mysql_real_escape_string stripslashes etc? or maybe I'm not getting you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing quote after $city_received

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert_new_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`password`,`age`,`sex`,`city`,`timereg`,`frcode`) VALUES ('".$fname_received."','".$lname_received."','".$email_received."','".$password_received."','".$dob_received."','".$sex_received."','".$city_received."','".$timepassreg."','".$frcode."')");
```

You missed `'` near `$city_received`

Also make sure you escape the user inputs.

Comment: This really makes no change to the original query

Comment: It does. Check `city_received`. Don't understand some downvoters. voting down without reading

Comment: @Companjo: You could have pointed it out that you added a single character. And a really small one also.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have escaped and checked your variables for valid input, it seems like you only forgot the `'` near `,'$city_received,`

```
<?php
$insert_new_user = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO users
    (fname, lname, email, password, age, sex, city, timereg, frcode)
VALUES
    ('$fname_received', '$lname_received', '$email_received', '$password_received', '$dob_received', '$sex_received', '$city_received', '$timepassreg', '$frcode')
");
```